# How to find this partial derivative using multivariable chain rule?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $$f(x,y,z)=x^3-y^2z^2$$ and also that $$x(u,v,w)=u+v,~y(u,v,w)=u-v,~z(u,v,w)=u+\sin{w}$$ if  $$f(x,y,z)=f(x(u,v,w),y(u,v,w),z(u,v,w))=F(u,v,w)$$ using the chain rule find $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$$

I am struggling with this problem here is what I tried so far, subbing in for $x,y,z$ into $f$. This was very messy and didn't use the chain rule so I assume it wasn't what was intended. Next I drew a tree diagram to help me figure out what $\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}$ was equal to. My problem with this was that I don't exactly know how to do this I know $F$ depends on $u,v,w$ but then to find out what these are functions of I rearranged the equations for $x,y,z$ above and got conflicting statements namely $u(v,x)$ and $u(v,y)$ so I am well and truly stuck.

Final thought was to find out what  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$$ was but I'm not sure that  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}$$.

I know this is trvial for many but I have never done this before thank you.

Comment: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}$. The problem is just using $F$ to mean "$f$ when considered as a function of $(u,v,w)$ instead of as a function of $(x,y,z)$."

Comment: Could you explain more please? I'm afraid I don't understand why this is the case and I don't get your second point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = (3x^2)(1)+(-2yz^2)(1)+(-2y^2z)(1)$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = 3x^2-2yz^2-2y^2z$$

Then substitute $x(u,v,w), \space y(u,v,w), \space and \space z(u,v,w)$ into $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ so you have everything in terms of $u,v$, and $w$.

Comment: PS: and good luck with your multivariable calculus course!

Comment: Thank you very much. I would just like to ask though how exactly do we know 100% that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}$$ and we just need to substitute in?

Comment: Don't get caught up too much on the notation until you are comfortable with the concepts. I wouldn't introduce $F$... I would just leave everything in terms of $f$. If you like, plug $u,~v,~w$ into $f$ and find $\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}$ and compare.

Comment: Okay thank you I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the composition:
\begin{alignat}{2}
\mathbf R^3&\xrightarrow{\quad g\quad}\mathbf R^3\xrightarrow{\quad f\quad}\mathbf R\\
\scriptstyle\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{bmatrix}&\longmapsto\rlap{\scriptstyle\begin{bmatrix}u+v\\ u-v\\ u+\sin w\end{bmatrix}}\\
&\phantom{\longmapsto\longmapsto}{\scriptstyle\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\y\end{bmatrix}}\longmapsto f(x,y,z)
\end{alignat}
We have $\; F(u,v,w)=f\bigl((x(u,v,w),y(u,v,w),z(u,v,w)\bigr)$, so
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial u}\\&=3x^2\cdot1-2yz^2\cdot1-2y^2z\cdot1=3x^2-2yz(y+z).
\end{align*}